# ZyBooks Lab:Seasons assignment - What's wrong with my code

Tags: python

Lab:Seasons assignment
Write a program that takes a date as input and outputs the date's season. The input is a string to represent the month and an int to represent the day.

Ex: If the input is:

April
11
the output is:

Spring
In addition, check if the string and int are valid (an actual month and day).

Ex: If the input is:

Blue
65
the output is:

Invalid
The dates for each season are:
Spring: March 20 - June 20
Summer: June 21 - September 21
Autumn: September 22 - December 20
Winter: December 21 - March 19

my code so far:

```
input_month = input()
input_day = int(input())

months = ('January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June','July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December')
if not (input_month in months):
    print ('Invalid')
    
elif input_month == 'January':
    if not (0 < input_day <= 31):
        print('Invalid')
    else:
        print('Winter')
        
elif input_month == 'February':
    if not (0 < input_day <= 29):
        print('Invalid')
    else:
        print('Winter')
        
elif input_month == 'March':
    if (0 < input_day < 20):
        print('Winter')
    elif (20 <= input_day <= 31):
        print('Spring')
    else:
        print('Invalid')
        
elif input_month == 'April':
    if not (0 < input_day <= 30):
        print('Invalid')
    else:
        print('Spring')
        
elif input_month == 'May':
    if not (0 < input_day <= 31):
        print('Invalid')
    else:
        print('Spring')
        
elif input_month == 'June':
    if (0 < input_day <= 20):
        print('Spring')
    elif (20 < input_day <= 30):
        print('Summer')
    else:
        print('Invalid')
        
elif input_month == 'July' or 'August':
    if not (0 < input_day <= 31):
        print('Invalid')
    else:
        print('Summer')
        
elif input_month == 'September':
    if not(0 < input_day <= 30):
        print("Invalid")
    elif (0 < input_day <= 21):
        print ("Summer")
    else:
        print ("Autumn")
        
elif input_month == 'October':
    if not (0 < input_day <= 31):
        print('Invalid')
    else:
        print('Autumn')
        
elif input_month == 'November':
    if not (0 < input_day <= 30):
        print('Invalid')
    else:
        print('Autumn')
        
elif input_month == 'December':
    if (0 < input_day <= 20):
        print('Autumn')
    elif (20 < input_day <= 31):
        print('Winter')
    else:
        print('Invalid')
```

I am getting errors for September 31 and November 7th and I can't figure out why?

Comment: Check out the output of `'September' == 'July' or 'August'`, that's not doing what you think it's doing, and is causing any date after August to behave unexpectedly.

Comment: To elaborate on the previous comment, you would want your July/August comparison to look like "elif input_month == 'July' or  input_month == 'August':" so to properly combine your "or" tests.

Comment: My preferred method is: `input_month in ('July', 'August')`